# How to add custom div (+php) code to wordpress site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am very new to wordpress. But have good knowledge in php, html, css and javascript.

I want to add custom  [font-resizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/font-resizer/installation/) to my wordpress site. as shown below for example.

[image: My theme image]

What would be the best and non-messy way to add the plugin code to my website.

I have looked at some tutorials online but it seems that I can't getting those. 
Any help would be appreciated. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add that plugin specifically to your site, then [its documentation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/font-resizer/installation/) suggests:

- adding it through a widget that the plugin creates
- or using this bit of code wherever you want in whichever template file: `<?php if(function_exists('fontResizer_place')) { fontResizer_place(); } ?>`

Does your theme have a place for widgets in its header? If not, you'll want to just place that bit of PHP somewhere in your `header.php` file.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the answer. it telling to add a php line of code "somewhere". I don't know where do I put the code. I want to put it on header but I saw header.php file and it doesn't have HTML code. It calls `<?php
// WordPress Head
wp_head();
?>
</head> `.  and I `wp_head()` is responsible for the header html code.

Comment: I can't add widget because I want to add it to a specific location and not as a widget.

Comment: Okay, normally, a theme would have a consistent header across all pages and it would keep the code for that in `header.php`, but in this case it may be across multiple template files. Have you checked any other template files, like `page.php`, for the HTML? Is it nowhere to be found?